# Spring boot doesn't read Components after jar signing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader, jarsigner

I am developing a Spring Boot Application that serves REST HTTP(S) requests. (pretty common).

It works as it is supposed, but after the final (and working) jar is signed (by a valid certificate) all URL mappings stop working, returning only 404 to any request. (Note that the embedded Tomcat server starts without problems and I don't receive any exception)

After some debugging I found that the Java's default ClassLoader (Laucher$AppClassLoader) just doesn't return the classes within the packages I configurated (@ComponentScan) when the jar is signed.

```
//org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
//Param 'path' has my valid, existing and desired package with @Controller or @Component inside
protected Set<Resource> doFindAllClassPathResources(String path) throws IOException {
            Set<Resource> result = new LinkedHashSet<Resource>(16);
            ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader(); //sun.misc.Laucher$AppClassLoader
            Enumeration<URL> resourceUrls = (cl != null ? cl.getResources(path) : ClassLoader.getSystemResources(path));
            //Empty enumeration when jar is signed
            ...
}
```

I tried to use a custom Class Loader without success; same problem.

Since it works when I sign the jar with a self signed certificate, I think that there may be a problem with the signing process that was done by another person. But I can't find any proof of that.

It appears that once signed, I can't list the package content...

I'll try some more tests and add here if I consider useful...

**UPDATE**

After debugging with the help of a custom Class Loader, I found that:

```
((java.net.JarURLConnection)new java.net.URL("jar:file:/home/user/my-app-with-dependencies_signed.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").openConnection()).getJarEntry();
```

Ok. Works.

```
((java.net.JarURLConnection)new java.net.URL("jar:file:/home/user/my-app-with-dependencies_signed.jar!/META-INF/").openConnection()).getJarEntry();
```

Doesn't work! >.<
It throws

```
Exception occurred in target VM: JAR entry META-INF/ not found in /home/user/my-app-with-dependencies_signed.jar 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry META-INF/ not found in /home/user/my-app-with-dependencies_signed.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:142)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarEntry(JarURLConnection.java:94)
...
```

This same second example works when trying to access a unsigned or self-signed jar.

This operation of opening the jar is performed by Spring when reading @Controller and @Component from the given packages in @ComponentScan.

In the same way, Java's Class Loader doesn't read directories content, only specified files.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader(); //sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").hasMoreElements(); //always true
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/").hasMoreElements(); //false when signed
```

**UPDATE 2**

I got the information about the signature. The people responsible for signatures and certificates actually uses a Windows applications that signs the jar with certificates from Windows-MY keystore and private key from a USB token.

Not that this is certainly the cause, but I think it is important to note that `jarsigner` is not used.

**UPDATE 3**

I created a github repository with a simple test case: 
https://github.com/jesjobom/signed-jar-class-loader-test

Comment: After reading the official doc, it seems the signing process involve updating MANIFEST.MF.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html

In your second case, it seems the MANIFEST.MF is missing. Did you check the content of your signed jar?

You could also try spring-boot-maven-plugin, it may repackage correctly your jar.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Comment: How do you run it? It's a jar file and your run it with java -jar or is it a servlet?

How do you sign your jar? Is it a plugin in maven, or externally?

Comment: I have verified the signature with `jarsigner -verify`. So everything should be ok, including MANIFEST.MF. But I did check some entries in this file. 
The signature is not done by me, so I wouldn't know the process (but I'll look into it). What I know is that this signature is valid. And in my tests I run the jar using `java -jar`.

Comment: Please could you compare the files in the two jars? Does one JAR have a "INDEX.LIST" file when the other does not? Are you able to upload your two JARs or a reduced repro case for us to examine?

Comment: I couldn't find any "INDEX.LIST" or anything like it in both jars, signed or self-signed. But I notice something odd... With the unsigned or self-signed jar I can list the directories using `unzip -l my-app-self_signed.jar "*/"`. But doing the same with the signed version won't list anything. This doesn't make sense since the folders exist, they have files inside, but they are not listed... I mean, a folder "org/springframework/util/" exists because it has the file "FileCopyUtils.class" inside, but the folder alone won't be listed from the signed jar while it is listed from the selfsigned one.

Comment: I'll try to generate a simple app for testing purposes and upload all versions. But it'll take some time because of the signature process...

Comment: New update with a project to test the problem. =)

Answer (score 1):

I have reached a solution but the problem still exists.

When loading the classes I pointed via `@ComponentScan` Spring asks the ClassLoader (`Laucher$AppClassLoader`) for the `java.net.URL` for each package I informed. Since, for some unknown reason, I can't load packages/folders, I created a custom ClassLoader that always return the expected URL if the package is mine.

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

...

@Override
public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
    if(name.startsWith("com/my/package/")) {
        readBasePath(); //obtains path to jar (e.g. "jar:file:/home/app.jar!/")
        List<URL> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        resources.add(new URL(basePath + name));
        return Collections.enumeration(resources);
    }
    return fallback.getResources(name); //default classloader
}
...
}
```

Even so, later, Spring tries to load the ".class" from the packages and fails for the same reasons... So, I created a custom implementation of `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` that will list all the content of the jar (this I can do!) and selects only those within the given package.

```
public class CustomPathMatchingResourceLoader extends PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver {

@Override
protected Set<Resource> doFindPathMatchingJarResources(final Resource rootDirResource, URL rootDirURL, String subPattern) throws IOException {

    try {

        String searchBase = ...; //package within jar
        String pathBase = ...; //path to jar

        URLConnection conn = new URL(pathBase).openConnection();

        Set<Resource> resources = new HashSet();
        JarFile file = ((JarURLConnection) conn).getJarFile();

        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = file.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName().startsWith(searchBase) && !entry.getName().endsWith("/")) {
                resources.add(new UrlResource(pathBase + entry.getName()));
            }
        }

        return resources;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(rootDirResource, rootDirURL, subPattern);
}
...
}
```

So it worked without any interference in the signing process... I am pretty confident that signing with `jarsigner` would solve the problem, but I think that it'd be difficult...

Anyway, although it worked, it's not a solution. Therefore, I will not accept this answer as the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the signed jar doesn't contain the entries `META-INF` and `com/jesjobom` **explicitly**.

Using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) you can list the zip entries: e.g. `7za l signed-jar-class-loader-test_signed.jar`

- Your **signed jar**:

  ```
     Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....         1907          999  com\jesjobom\Main.class
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....         2978          944  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom\signed-jar-class-loader-test\pom.xml
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....          113          111  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom\signed-jar-class-loader-test\pom.properties
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....          595          361  META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....          609          386  META-INF\BANCO_DO_BRASIL_SA.SF
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....         4520         3251  META-INF\BANCO_DO_BRASIL_SA.RSA
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-02-27 15:27:08              10722         6052  6 files
  ```
- **After it's compiled** there are some **`D`** (directories) entries, that are missing in the signed version.

  ```
      Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  META-INF
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  com
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  com\jesjobom
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  META-INF\maven
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 D....            0            0  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom\signed-jar-class-loader-test
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....         1907          999  com\jesjobom\Main.class
  2018-03-09 14:15:16 .....         3082          949  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom\signed-jar-class-loader-test\pom.xml
  2018-02-27 15:27:08 .....          117          114  META-INF\maven\com.jesjobom\signed-jar-class-loader-test\pom.properties
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-02-27 15:27:08               5324         2221  4 files, 6 folders
  ```

I don't know why the folder entries are missing. I suspect that because they don't have a SHA signature in `\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` they are removed from the signed JAR.